# How can I get active record to throw an exception if there are too many records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Following the principle of [fail-fast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast):

When querying the database where there should only ever be one record, I want an exception if `.first()` ([first](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-first)) encounters more than one record.

I see that there is a [first!](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-first-21) method that throws if there's less records than expected but I don't see anything for if there's two or more.

How can I get active record to fail early if there are more records than expected?

Is there a reason that active record doesn't work this way?

I'm used to C#'s [Single()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.single?view=netframework-4.7.2) that will throw if two records are found.

Comment: It would be easier to just validate this than to raise an error. If this is a relationship then `has_one` will already take care of this for you.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. In this case there's only one for a specific filter (scope) but there are more of a different type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you expect activerecord's `first` method to fails if there are more than 1 record? it makes no sense for it to work that way.

You can define your own class method the count the records before getting the first one. Something like

```
def self.first_and_only!
  raise "more than 1" if size > 1
  first!
end
```

That will raise an error if there are more than 1 and also if there's no record at all. If there's one and only one it will return it.

Comment: Nice. How about adding a bang to that method to indicate that it is error raising? Also, how about using the `one?` method mentioned by Ursus? (Like, perhaps, `raise "more than one" unless one?`.)

Comment: I thought about that `one?` method, but I wanted this to rise two different errors if more than one and if none. Using `one?` would be an option of course, but it would do a slightly different thing. It all depends on the requirement though. And yeah, a `! `at the end of the method's name would also be a good practice, sure!.

Comment: You could use `many?` then instead e.g. `raise "more than 1" if many?`

Comment: @engineersmnky hmmm, looks like the `many?` methods uses `to_a.many?` in some cases, maybe `count > 1` is safer just to count, but it can be used though https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/Relation/many%3F (check the source). EDIT: I guess `size > 1` would be better

Comment: @arieljuod not in your case though. In your case it is identical to `count > 1` because `size` is `count` in this case

Answer (score 3):

### find_sole_by (Rails 7.0+)

Starting from `Rails 7.0`, there is a [`find_sole_by`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_sole_by) method:

> Finds the sole matching record. Raises `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` if no record is found. Raises `ActiveRecord::SoleRecordExceeded` if more than one record is found.

For example:

```rb
Product.find_sole_by(["price = %?", price])
```

**Sources:**

- [ActiveRecord::FinderMethods#find_sole_by](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.4/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_sole_by).
- [Rails 7 adds ActiveRecord methods `#sole` and `#find_sole_by`](https://blog.saeloun.com/2021/03/16/rails-adds-sole-and-find-sole-by.html).
- [Rails 7.0 adds ActiveRecord::FinderMethods 'sole' and 'find_sole_by'](https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/rails-7-adds-active-record-finder-methods).

Answer (score 2):

It seems ActiveRecord has no methods like that. One useful method I found is [one?](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-one-3F), you can call it on an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object. You could do

```
users = User.where(name: "foo")
raise StandardError unless users.one?
```

and maybe define your own custom exception

Comment: I do not think it is a good practice to use StandError since it's going to handle more than this specific one. Its best to define a custom one

Answer (score 1):

If you care enough about queries performance, you have to avoid `ActiveRecord::Relation`'s `count`, `one?`, `none?`, `many?`, `any?` etc, which spawns SQL `select count(*) ...` query.

So, your could use SQL `limit` like:

```
def self.single!
  # Only one fast DB query
  result = limit(2).to_a
  # Array#many? not ActiveRecord::Calculations one
  raise TooManySomthError if result.many?
  # Array#first not ActiveRecord::FinderMethods one
  result.first
end
```

Also, when you expect to get only one record, you have to use Relation's `take` instead of `first`. The last one is for really *first* record, and can produce useless SQL `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @engineersmnky Very strange question. You could just test `select count(*) from table where condition` vs `select * from table where condition limit 2` on 1M table where `condition` meet, say, 10+%.

Comment: @engineersmnky the only non-broken ActiveRecord::Relation methods are `exists?` and `take`, when `many?` etc are using `count` under the hood. They are doing this "just because" of DRY: when association is preloaded, `count` duck types to `Array#count`, when is not - to SQL `select count(*)`.

Comment: @engineersmnky Accepted answer has 2(!) SQL queries, which is >> object instantiation. And yes, 2 queries + SQL `count` + SQL `ORDER BY` >>>> one extra AR object instantiation (because we have to return one).

Comment: @engineersmnky Anyway, you can test accepted answer time vs my answer on any DB size, significant for prod one.